# Read XML using XMLReader in PHP without know nodes

Tags: php, xml, xmlreader

I have to read and parse an XML file using XMLReader with PHP without know the nodes.

I have this file:

```
<Invoices>
  <Company>
    <Name>Tuttobimbi Srl</Name>
  </Company>
  <Documents>
    <Document>
      <CustomerCode>0055</CustomerCode>
      <CustomerWebLogin></CustomerWebLogin>
      <CustomerName>Il Puffetto</CustomerName>
    </Document>
  </Documents>
</Invoices>
```

I would to parse it like this:

```
Invoices
Invoices, Company
Invoices, Company, Name
Invoices, Documents
Invoices, Documents, Document
etc...
```

I wrote this code:

```
    while ($xml->read()) {
        if ($xml->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT)
            array_push($a, $xml->name);

        if ($xml->nodeType == XMLReader::END_ELEMENT)
            array_pop($a);

        if ($xml->nodeType == XMLReader::TEXT) {
            if (!in_array(implode(",", $a), $result)) {
                $result[] = implode(",", $a);
            }
        }
    }
```

It seems to work but doesn't print the nodes with subnodes, such as:

```
Invoices
Invoices, Company
Invoices, Documents
Invoices, Documents, Document
```

Comment: You need to iterate over each node's children as well.

Comment: @PaulCrovella My mistake. I'm used to using [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php), hence my false assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many of those nodes you'd think would be `XMLReader::TEXT` nodes are actually `XMLReader::SIGNIFICANT_WHITESPACE`.

Fortunately you can drop that `$xml->nodeType == XMLReader::TEXT` check altogether and build your result as you encounter elements.

Example:

```
while ($xml->read()) {
    if ($xml->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT) {
        array_push($a, $xml->name);
        $result[] = implode(",", $a);
    }

    if ($xml->nodeType == XMLReader::END_ELEMENT) {
        array_pop($a);
    }
}
```

This'll give you:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Invoices
    [1] => Invoices,Company
    [2] => Invoices,Company,Name
    [3] => Invoices,Documents
    [4] => Invoices,Documents,Document
    [5] => Invoices,Documents,Document,CustomerCode
    [6] => Invoices,Documents,Document,CustomerWebLogin
    [7] => Invoices,Documents,Document,CustomerName
)
```

Comment: Thanks @paul-crovella, I used your first solution to not repeat element in the array. Thanks

Comment: now I have a problem...into "if (!empty($a) && !in_array(implode(",", $a), $result)) {" I need also to save into an other array the value of the node. When I try "$xml->value" I have no value inside...